# same UUID on bluetooth devices paired with android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I started into looking into the bluetooth and android communication. So I purchased one arduino-compatible breakout and shield from the same vendor. So I paired these two with the android app that I am working on, but I realized that these two products return the identical UUID like this. I purchased these from the same vendor.

02-18 10:51:24.089: D/ActivateFragment(26721): UUID: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
02-18 10:51:24.089: D/ActivateFragment(26721): UUID: 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

Here is my android app code printing out the UUIDs.

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i(TAG, "daction=="+  action);

        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
            //discovery starts, we can show progress dialog or perform other tasks
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            //discovery finishes, dismis progress dialog
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                   //bluetooth device found
            BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Log.i(TAG, "bluetooth name is "+ device.getName());
            if (device == null || device.getName() == null || device.getName().isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Found device " + device.getName() + "=="+ device.getAddress() + "=="+ device.getBondState() + "=="+  device.getType());
            ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();
            if (uuids == null) {
                return;
            }
            for (ParcelUuid uuid: uuids) {
                Log.d(TAG, "UUID: " +  uuid.getUuid().toString());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

So I can't connect to two bluetooth from the android app. Once the app is connected to it, it can't connect to the next one. And the funny thing is 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb works fine, but 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb doesn't work.

I thought that there is something wrong with my app, but when I have it connect to it (one is active, but the other is not active) one at a time, it connects to both.

Is the UUID embedded in the bluetooth device and android get it from the bluetooth device or is randomly assigned by the android phone?

I'd appreciated if someone who knows about the relationship point me to a website or any tutorial.

Comment: Hey do you find any soln for this prob??